# Solid stain on untreated exterior wood

Tags: wood, exterior, staining

I am putting together a bar top on my deck, and don't want to use pressure treated wood on the top surface (as I understand it that would be ill advised for an eating area). An option I am considering id using untreated Southern Yellow Pine lumber that is covered in solid stain.

Will the stain provide any protection against the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done more digging, and this is what I've found:

**Paint**

- Sits on top of the wood and is capable of forming a sheen
- Is good at keeping moisture out, but traps whatever moisture that does get in
- Should be easier to clean food / drink spills off

**Stain**

- Can't be applied over a previously painted surface (not a problem in my case).
- Bonds to the wood more closely than paint because it actually soaks in
- Allows moisture to leave the wood.
- Does not form a sheen - leaves original texture of the wood exposed

In my application, I chose to go with paint. I applied two coats of exterior paint with "built in" primer.

Answer (score 0):

A protective stain would help keep the wood from the elements, a spar varnish would be better, plus give you the advantage of wipe-ability.